# Arduino preprocessor misbehaving with defined terms WIFI_AP and WIFI_STA

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

The Arduino.cc preprocessor (latest version as of may 1 2020) has unexpected behaviour when I try to do preprocessor logic to recognize the defines words WIFI_AP or WIFI_STA.

```
Example:
#define FOO WIFI_STA

#if (FOO) == (WIFI_AP)
   Serial.print ("if this the this is zero: ");
   Serial.print( ((FOO) == (WIFI_AP)));  // should eval to 0
   Serial.println( " then there is no way to reach here!!!");
#endif
```

**Results in** 
"if this is zero: 0   then there is no way to reach here!!!"

**Expected behavior:**
  the preprocessor should evaluate the same logic in the print statement and remove all the prints before compilation!

**Regression:**
 1.  Does not happen for all possible defined constants, just WIFI_STA
    and WIFI_AP.

2. WIFI_STA and WIFI_AP evaluate to 1 and 2 respectively.  Don't know types.
3. grep cannot find any place in the includes or arduino app resources where WIFI_STA and WIFI_AP are defined!

I'm really confused.  I'm thinking maybe WIFI_STA are constants that are not defined at the time the preprocessor runs.  But I don't know how to do this differently/

**Full Code** that will run and show both the expected result and the unexpected result

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>


#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
#define THREE 3

#define FOO ONE

#define WIFIACCESSMODE WIFI_STA

void setup_wifiActivate() {
    Serial.println(WIFIACCESSMODE);
    Serial.println(WIFI_STA);
    Serial.println(WIFI_AP);
    Serial.println(WIFI_AP_STA);

// select mode for connection
 WiFi.mode(WIFIACCESSMODE);
 // WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);         //Only Access point
//  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);   //This line hides the viewing of ESP as wifi network
//  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);   //Both AP hotspot and router client are enabled

#if (WIFIACCESSMODE) == (WIFI_AP)
       Serial.println("Wifi access mode is WIFI_AP");
       Serial.println( (WIFIACCESSMODE) );
       Serial.println((WIFI_AP) );
       Serial.println( (WIFIACCESSMODE) == (WIFI_AP) );
   //setup_WiFiAccessPoint();

#elif (WIFIACCESSMODE) == (WIFI_AP_STA)
   Serial.println("Wifi access mode is WIFI_AP_STA");
   // setup_WiFiAccessPoint();
  //  setup_WiFiRouter();


  #elif  (WIFIACCESSMODE) == (WIFI_STA)
      Serial.println("Wifi access mode is WIFI_STA");
   // setup_WiFiRouter();

    #else
      Serial.println("Wifi Access mode is Unknown");
    #endif



}

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Serialdone");

  #if FOO == TWO
    Serial.println(FOO);
    Serial.println(ONE);
    Serial.println(TWO);
    Serial.println(THREE);
    Serial.println(FOO == TWO);

    Serial.println("It's two");
  #elif FOO == ONE
        Serial.println(FOO);
    Serial.println(ONE);
    Serial.println(TWO);
    Serial.println(THREE);
    Serial.println(FOO == TWO);
    Serial.println("it's ONE");
  #elif FOO == THREEE
             Serial.println(FOO);
    Serial.println(ONE);
    Serial.println(TWO);
    Serial.println(THREE);
    Serial.println(FOO == TWO);
    Serial.println("it's THREE");
  #else
            Serial.println(FOO);
    Serial.println(ONE);
    Serial.println(TWO);
    Serial.println(THREE);
    Serial.println(FOO == TWO);
    Serial.println("it's Unknown");
  #endif
  setup_wifiActivate();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

What am I trying to do?
I am trying to let the user write something like this:

```
// edit to set desired access mode  WIFI_AP  WIFI_STA WIFI_AP_STA
#define WIFIACCESSMODE WIFI_STA
...
then later:
WiFi.mode( WIFIACCESSMODE);
#if WIFIACCESSMODE == WIFI_STA   <<<---  this fails to work
  // do some code
#endif
```

Can someone tell me

1. the origin of the problem
2. how to work around it
3. Where WIFI_STA is defined.

I'm using an ESP8266 but this problem is in the compiler not the device.

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the ESP8266WiFi library - 
MacOSX For built in packages Control-Click on `/Applications/Arduino.app` and select "Show Package Contents" from the pop-up menu.  From there you can drill down to;

```
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/packages
```

ESP8266 package (at least on my OSX Sierra) `Users\YOUR_USERNAME\Library\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.1\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src`

Windows `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.1\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src` - you find in `ESP8266WiFiType.h` the following definition

```
typedef enum WiFiMode 
{
    WIFI_OFF = 0, WIFI_STA = 1, WIFI_AP = 2, WIFI_AP_STA = 3,
    /* these two pseudo modes are experimental: */ WIFI_SHUTDOWN = 4, WIFI_RESUME = 8
} WiFiMode_t;
```

So for your application you have to use:

```
if (WIFIACCESSMODE == WIFI_STA ) {do STA things}
if (WIFIACCESSMODE == WIFI_AP) {do AP things}
```

Comment: First thank you.  Second I'm on mac osx so that path doesn't exist.  I ran grep -r over the application folder as well as my homefolder library and sketchbook looking for these symbols and got nothing defining them, just places they are used.  Third, your answer however solved the problem because now I will be able to declare my own variable with the type WiFiMode whch is what I had no way of knowing before.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently WIFI_STA and WIFI_AP are code-defined constants and not preprocessor definitions.  thus the only way to select on these values is to use explicit code not preprocessor optimizations via C++ if or case statements.

```
if (WIFIACCESSMODE == WIFI_AP) {
       Serial.println("Wifi access mode is WIFI_AP");
       Serial.println( (WIFIACCESSMODE) );
       Serial.println((WIFI_AP) );
       Serial.println( (WIFIACCESSMODE) == (WIFI_AP) );
   //setup_WiFiAccessPoint();
}
else if((WIFIACCESSMODE) == (WIFI_AP_STA)){
   Serial.println("Wifi access mode is WIFI_AP_STA");
   // setup_WiFiAccessPoint();
  //  setup_WiFiRouter();
}

else if ((WIFIACCESSMODE) == (WIFI_STA)) {
      Serial.println("Wifi access mode is WIFI_STA");
   // setup_WiFiRouter();
}
    else {
      Serial.println("Wifi Access mode is Unknown");
    }
```

works.

**HOWEVER I STILL DON"T KNOW WHERE THE CODE LIES THAT THESE ARE DEFINED.**